# Buttons show up on Debug but not on regular run of application on Eclipse for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, button, invisible

I have a weird problem that only started recently.  When I run the app normally from eclipse, my buttons don't show up on the main screen (however if I click where they are supposed to be, it registers the event).  But when I start the app using the debug mode, the buttons show up right where they are supposed to be!  This is with no changes in code.  Both buttons are also set to be "visible" in the layout.

Anyone know why this is?  I pasted the relevant code from my main screen, I commented everything else out...

```
package com.android.market.companionpushup;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainScreen extends Activity {
public static String mWorkout;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainscreen);

    // Create database helper
//  mDbHelper = new WorkoutDbAdapter(this);

    createAndRegisterButtons();
}

private void createAndRegisterButtons() {
    Button GoButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
    Button TestButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.test);

    GoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
 //             int workout = chooseWorkout();
 //             startWorkout(workout);
        } // end onClick
    }); // end of GoButton


    TestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
 //             startWorkout(100);
        } // end onClick        
    }); // end of TetsButton

} // end of createAndRegisterButtons
 // 

 }
```

Comment: Nothing wrong in your code, but what does your xml look like ? And what do you call debug mode ?

Comment: It won't let me post my XML file but I don't think there is anything wrong with it.  It is just a basic screen with 2 buttons.  As for what I call debug mode....I'm not sure what the question is but its when the breakpoints are activated in your code so you can step through it.

Comment: Did you try to clean up the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up restarting the computer and phone and it worked.